# Cannot access remote MySQL database in shell

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first time working with a remote MySQL database and I can't seem to access it correctly in the shell command prompt.

I am provided with the following specifications of the MySQL server and the credentials to access it.

```
DATABASE = {
    'host': 'sample.abc.lan',
    'account': 'accountName',
    'pwd': '123456',
    'db_name': 'databaseName',
    'machine_name': "https://machineName.something.com/"
}
```

After doing some research online, I found that the command to access a remote MySQL database is

```
mysql -u {username} -p'{password}' \
    -h {remote server ip or name} -P {port} \
    -D {DB name}
```

In my case, I tried (on the ssh server):

```
shell> mysql -u accountName -p 123456 -h sample.abc.lan -P 3306 -D databaseName
```

However, this did not work as intended. After executing the line above, I'm prompted to enter the password. After entering the password, an error message is returned:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'accountName'@'%' to database '123456'
```

I can't seem to figure out how to work around this error and I would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: You can't have a space between `-p` and the password.

Comment: Have you whitelisted your IP in server?

Comment: That's why it thinks `123456` is the database name.

Comment: I tried the script that doesn't have a space between `-p` and the password. The same error is returned.

Comment: @user3045457 I don't have direct access to the MySQL server. The only information given to me is displayed above.

Comment: Try the same commandline, without the `123456`. Mysql should ask for the password.

Comment: @Luuk My access is denied and ERROR 1045 (28000) is returned. Any fixes for this?

Comment: The shortest, and maybe best answer, is to contact the administrator of that server....